# Jenkins pipeline retrieving Git branch and hash

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to retrieve the git branch and hash in the Jenkins pipeline but for some strange reason, the stdout for branch in particular always comes back as 'HEAD'. If I run the exact command in bash it works just fine. I get 'develop' and the hash.

**Pipeline**

```
stage('Build') {
    script {
        GIT_BRANCH = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD").trim()
        GIT_HASH = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse --short HEAD").trim()
    }
    echo "branch is: ${GIT_BRANCH}"
    echo "hash is: ${GIT_HASH}"
}
```

**Output**

```
Running shell script
+ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
Running shell script
+ git rev-parse --short HEAD
branch is: HEAD
hash is: dd96820
```

Comment: This is symptomatic of using a detached HEAD. That's normal for Jenkins, which likes to use a detached HEAD.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the branch name in the pipeline then? The standard env variables such as GIT_BRANCH doesn't work at all in pipeline it seems.

Comment: I'm no Jenkins expert. A lot of stuff in Jenkins seems quite wrong-headed to me, including this strange taste for detached HEAD mode, but there's probably some reason for it and something to do about it—I just have no idea what.

Comment: It definitely seems strange. Furthermore, the env variables for pipeline seems to be very limited and I can't find any working method to inject additional variables along with the default set. I'm having to run the script block at each stage block in order to make the variable accessible when I want it to be global...

Answer (score 0):

That seems related to [issue JENKINS-45962](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45962): "`GIT_BRANCH` variable is not populated in jenkins pipeline"

It refers to [JENKINS-26100](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26100), which allows SCM steps to return the revision state (not the branch).

Hence the comment:

> I don't plan to change this, since JENKINS-26100 allows the checkout step (and the git step) to return a map of names and values from the checkout.
>
> Pipelines can (and often do) use multiple checkout steps, and it is cleaner, safer, and more understandable to store the returned values for a specific checkout in a map than it is to read environment variables and decide which checkout provided which environment variables.

Since there are *multiple* checkout step, *one* environment variable (like `GIT_BRANCH`) is no longer populated.
Since HEAD is always detached, ... `rev-parse` would always return a commit, not a branch name.